# Use fullpage only in Appendix part of the document

Tags: appendix, fullpage

In my document (uses llncs.cls) I would like to use \usepackage{fullpage} only in appendix part, not in the initial 10pages. Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Can you mention for what purpose you need to use this package?

Comment: @MadyYuvi For a research report.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that do you need this package for full page image or table, etc. Hope I'm clear now...

Comment: for Full images

Answer (score 1):

Based on your reply in `comments`, please use the option `p` for full page imagess, and the `MWE` is:

```
...
\usepackage{stfloats}
\begin{document}

...

\begin{figure}[p]
....
\end{figure}
```

As you are not provided `MWE`, I've mentioned the `image` code only